# WGPU - Rust или С/C++?

Tags: c++, rust

Подскажите пожалуйста насчет библиотеки Wgpu: https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu

На странице сказано:

```
C/C++
To use wgpu in C/C++, you need wgpu-native.
```

wgpu-native: https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu-native

Переходу на страницу гитхаб wgpu-native, такм сказано, что:

```
This is a native WebGPU implementation in Rust, based on wgpu-core.
```

Что то я запутался - пишут про С/C++, а когда переходишь на страницу - пишут опять про Rust.

Comment: wgpu-native написана на rust, но может использоваться из C/C++, так как там есть С интерфейс.

Comment: @user7860670, Спасибо. А в чем тогда разница между wgpu-core и wgpu-native ?

Comment: Прежде чем задавать такие вопросы следует прочитать описание этих проектов, там все написано...